# Laravel - Get last 5 registered users attributes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make a dashboard and I want to display the last 5 users that are registered on the site, So the most recent 5 registered people. How can I accomplish this? I need to have access to all their attributes, for instance, Name, Lastname etc.

This is my route: `Route::get('/adminpanel', 'AdminController@index')->name('adminpanel');`

And this is the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    Carbon::setLocale('nl');
    $tijd = Carbon::today();
    $posts = Post::count();
    $users = User::count();
    $replies = Reply::count();

    return view('admin.dashboard', compact('posts', 'users', 'replies', 'tijd'));

}
```

They need to be displayed in a table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Lastname</th>
   <th>Email</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <th scope="row">1</th>
 <td>Rainier</td>
 <td>Laan</td>
 <td>rainier.laan@home.nl</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `take()` to get specific number of records.

```
$users = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

And on your `view`-

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{$user->name}}
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This one will take 5 latest users.

```
$users = User::latest()->take(5)->get();
```